# How to parse extremely large file of json stream to valid JSON

Tags: python, json, bash, jq, large-files

I'm working on a CS course project where I've to perform sentiment analysis of Twitter data on an Ubuntu VM. I was able to build a crawler to obtain the data but I have the output in the format of a file of JSON stream which is a very large file which is of the style:

```
{
  "query": "#India_since_2019",
  "username": "user_1",
  "ID": "123455",
  "tweet": "This is the tweet",
  "datetime": "2019-04-05"
}
{
  "query": "#India_since_2019",
  "username": "user_1",
  "ID": "123455",
  "tweet": "This is the tweet",
  "datetime": "2019-04-05"
}
```

and so on.

I essentially have to filter results based on year and store the resultant json file.

The output I'm looking to get is

```
[
{
      "query": "#India_since_2019",
      "username": "user_1",
      "ID": "123455",
      "tweet": "This is the tweet",
      "datetime": "2019-04-05"
    },
    {
      "query": "#India_since_2019",
      "username": "user_1",
      "ID": "123455",
      "tweet": "This is the tweet",
      "datetime": "2019-04-05"
    }
]
```

This prevents me from reading the file line by line as all the data is appended thus not creating any new lines.

I tried using jq to parse the data but the file was too large and thus created errors.

Would you guys have any suggestions for how I can convert this easily to a valid JSON and write to another file?

I'd be open to solutions in any script as I'm flexible with those, although I'd prefer an idea I can work with in Python/Shell.

Thanks!

Comment: `jq` has a streaming option available, but how would you like to parse it? and what values would you like to store?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's your expected output given the above example? What did you try? Would `jq -c . file.json` work?

Comment: The streaming option (i.e. —stream) seems to be irrelevant here.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've edited my question to include the output I'm looking for. I essentially need to filter for a certain year and then store the results as a json object in a file.

Answer (score 1):

One of the major advantages of jq is that it is stream-oriented, so there should be no need to convert your stream of JSON entities to an array of those entities, unless that is the goal.  All processing should be done using `input` and/or `inputs`, most likely with the -n command-line option.

In other words, it might be advisable to perform all the processing in jq rather than converting the stream to a single, unmanageably large JSON entity for some tool that cannot deal with a stream.

Alternatively, if you wish to use a tool that requires JSONL input, then use `jq -cn inputs` (or `jq -c .` as suggested above).

Comment: So I'm aiming to process the JSON in jq by filtering for the year I require and then returning the JSON file. The `jq -c . file.json` didn't seem to work as all it did was pretty print my data rather than actually convert it to the desired output.

Comment: So use jq to filter the stream!